# Reduce Excel tab size beyond minimum. (Windows 7, Excel 2013)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, tabs

I want to be able to reduce the size of the tabs in Excel. I have a relatively large screen, set to maximum available resolution, and work with Excel files with 100s of tabs.
When creating Excel files I make tab labels absolute minimum length, but renaming other Excel files is not practical

Most forums advise ways to increase tab size using Scrollbar options. I have reduced Scrollbar size below (default) 17, down to 10, but this will not reduce the tabs size below a default size.
Does anyone know how I can make tab text size and tab size smaller?
Alternately, is there any way to reduce the horizontal buffer/margin inside the tab label?

Comment: Do you know you can right-click on the tabs, so that you get a list of all the tabs much easier to use when you are using many tabs? At least it works for me on Office 2016.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and yes, I am aware that I can navigate through tabs by right clicking on the navigation arrows in the far left corner (opening the tab activation menu), as well as moving tabs from their current location next to each other.

Comment: The vitiating factor for this solution is the lack of any ability to sort within the activation menu, or 'find/search' - I move the mouse over to the activation menu, then use the mouse to scroll through hundreds of tabs to find the tab I need.

Comment: I was really hoping Excel 2016 would introduce the option to customize size of tabs and ability to 'wrap' the tabs - I would be more than happy to sacrifice some horizontal space on the screen

Comment: So you're alternatively looking for a quick way to be presented all of the tabs so you can quickly go to one?

Comment: That is correct, Batman - and not just one, but to be able to navigate back and forth across multiple tabs where I cannot relocate the arrangement of the tabs (due to multiple macro/formula requiring tabs to remain in position)